# Mapbox GL: how to style layer of "markers" with clustering layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have three layers: (1), (2), and (3).

(1) Markers (not actually Mapbox GL Markers since I'm using layers but I don't know how to call them, maybe they are the Mapbox GL Markers in the background, I don't know):

```
map.addLayer({
        id: 'location-point',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'locations',
        filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
        layout: {
            'icon-image': 'balloon',
            'icon-size': [
                'case',
                ['==', ['get', 'id'], mapLocationActive], //highlight active marker
                0.55,
                0.35
            ],
            'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
            'text-size': 20,
        },
        paint: {
            'icon-color': 'orange',
        },
    });
```

This all works as expected and once the user clicks on a marker it increases it's size from 0.35 to 0.55 and back.

(2) Then I have the clustering layer:

```
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'clusters',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'locations',
            filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
            paint: {
                'circle-color': [
                    'step',
                    ['get', 'point_count'],
                    'orange',
                    3,
                    'orange',
                    5,
                    'orange'
                ],
                'circle-opacity': 0.85,
                'circle-radius': [
                    'step',
                    ['get', 'point_count'],
                    20,
                    3,
                    30,
                    5,
                    40
                ]
            }
        });
```

(3) And another layer to present the number of clustered markers inside of each cluster:

```
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'cluster-count',
            type: 'symbol',
            source: 'locations',
            filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
            layout: {
                'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
                'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                'text-size': 15,
            },
            paint: {
                'text-color': 'white',
            },
        });
```

At the moment, the only thing I can change dynamically (via `mapLocationActive`) is the marker size. I would like to have a bit more distinction between active and inactive markers but I don't know what visual properties of a marker can be easily updated. I had two ideas which I tried to test out but neither is working.

1. change the color and style of markers inside of `location-point` layer

```
paint: {
    'icon-color': [
        'case',
         ['==', ['get', 'id'], mapLocationActive], //highlight active marker
         'orange',
         'white'
    ],
    'icon-opacity': 0.85,
},
```

but this doesn't work as, I suppose, the coloring is defined once the layer is created and future changes are not possible and they would affect all markers.

2. adding another icon `balloon-outlined` and updating `icon-image`

```
'icon-image': [
   'case',
   ['==', ['get', 'id'], mapLocationActive], //highlight active marker
   'balloon',
   'balloon-outlined'
],
```

But this also didn't work. It's possible that I messed up something here as I need a break and I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work. Also, when trying to implement this, I ended up with squares as markers and not my SDF png image.

My question is, what is the best approach to style clustered markers. I don't want to lose the clustering. Ideally I'd like to be able to style clusters dynamically as well and hopefully once I figure this out then styling of clusters would be straightforward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The code above is the initialization code and the icon dynamic resizing is not handled there.

I've implemented this long time ago and missed the function at the bottom handling the actual marker highlighting

```
function highlightMarker(options, geoJsonData, vm) {
    vm.map.setLayoutProperty(
        'location-point',
        'icon-size',
        [
            'case',
            ['==', ['get', 'id'], vm.mapLocationActive], //highlight active marker
            0.55,
            0.35
        ]
    )
}
```

Changing this to

```
function highlightMarker(options, geoJsonData, vm) {
    vm.map.setLayoutProperty(
        'location-point',
        'icon-size',
        [
            'case',
            ['==', ['get', 'id'], vm.mapLocationActive], //highlight active marker
            0.55,
            0.35
        ]
    );
    vm.map.setLayoutProperty(
        'location-point',
        'icon-image',
        [
            'case',
            ['==', ['get', 'id'], vm.mapLocationActive], //highlight active marker
            'balloon',
            'circle'
        ]
    );
}
```

and everything works.
Hopefully this helps someone.